# How to get link_to in Rails output an SEO friendly url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, seo, hyperlink, link-to

My link_to tag is:

```
<%= link_to("My test title",{:controller=>"search", :action=>"for-sale", :id=> listing.id, :title => listing.title, :search_term => search_term}) %>
```

and produces this ugly URL:

```
http://mysite.com/search/for-sale/12345?title=premium+ad+%2B+photo+%5Btest%5D
```

How can I get link_to to generate:

```
http://mysite.com/search/for-sale/listing-title/search-term/12345
```

Been trying this a few different ways and cannot find much online, really appreciate any help!

Comment: Have you looked at things like slugify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tahe a look at [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

add this in your config/routes.rb

```
map.connect ':controller/:action/:title/search_item/:id', :controller=>'search', :action=>'for_sale'
```

restart your server and check.
Hope that helps :)

Comment: Here is a more detailed answer for Rails 3: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794231/how-to-add-article-title-to-url-using-link-to-in-rails-app/4794319#4794319

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the URL structure in routes.rb to match what you want the URL to look like, and parse the parameters accordingly in your controller method's args.