# How to add article title to URL using link_to in Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, seo, link-to

I am trying to follow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718439/how-to-get-link-to-in-rails-output-an-seo-friendly-url/2718494#2718494) to question

[How to get link_to in Rails output an SEO friendly url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718439/how-to-get-link-to-in-rails-output-an-seo-friendly-url)

but don't get the result. In my Rails 3 app I have:

```
# routes.rb
match '/articles/:id/:title' => 'articles#show'
resources :articles

# articles/index.html.haml
- @articles.each do |article|
  = link_to article.title, article, :title => article.title
```

However, after restarting the server, the links don't have the title: /articles/1, /articles/2

What is wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `link_to` will be using the route from `resources :articles`. If you want it to use the custom route you've defined, name the route, and then use that in your `link_to`:

```
# routes.rb
match '/articles/:id/:title' => 'articles#show', :as => :article_with_title

# articles/index.html.erb
link_to article.title, article_with_title_path(article, :title => article.title)
```

Also, you may want to consider looking into using [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id). It does this for you, but more transparently.

Comment: I removed my answer which was incomplete and editing it would duplicate yours. I will mention that friendly_id is awesome but a different solution to that posted.

Comment: thanks! `friendly_id` is more than I need. May be you know how one can make an universal helper for handling various routes `/articles/:id/:title`, `/users/:id/:name` etc., i.e. similar to SO routes?

Comment: Have you tried searching for that? There's a bunch of very similar questions on SO - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434266 for one..

Comment: all of them suggest `friendly_id` which works with `/articles/:title` and is unnecessary in my case, since I already have `id` in the routes. The problem is that I don't know how to make an universal logic for my models appending the extra part to the routes.

Comment: Just want to add that you'll probably want to add the `routes.rb` line suggested AFTER you state `resources :articles` otherwise you might have an issue with your edit links routing to show page.