# Reducing redundancy in Rails routes and url helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, seo, routes, helper

I want to add article's title to its url similarly to SO URLs. I was suggested to use the following setup in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794231/how-to-add-article-title-to-url-using-link-to-in-rails-app/4794319#4794319) to my another question

```
# routes.rb
match '/articles/:id/:title' => 'articles#show', :as => :article_with_title

# articles/index.html.erb
link_to  article.title, article_with_title_path(article, :title => article.title.downcase.gsub(/[^a-z0-9]+/,' ').strip.gsub(/\s+/,'-'))
```

It works, however I find it a bit redundant. Is there a way to make it nicer? What about an additional universal method to handle multiple routes?

```
match '/articles/:id/:title' => 'articles#show'
match '/users/:id/:name' => 'users#show'
etc.
```

Remarks:

1. Currently the following routes work fine: `/article/:id/:action`, `/article/:id/:title` with a condition that article cannot have titles `edit, show, index, etc.`
2. I believe `friendly_id` is unnecessary here, since the routes contain `:id` explicitly.
3. As I see, SO uses different routes for questions `/question/:id/:title`, `/posts/:id/:action` and for users `/users/:id/:name`, `/users/:action/:id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just override `to_param` in your models. Untested example from memory:

```
def to_param
  self.id + "-" + self.name.parameterize
end
```

this approach means you don't have to change the router, and can also keep using `Model.find(params[:id])` or similar.

Basically what the Railscast mentioned in another answer does, and the core of what [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) does too.

Answer (score 1):

Ryan Bates did an excellent [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url) on using the model's name, or any other attribute, in the url instead of the id.